# Issue in choosing data with '%' and work on it in pandas

Tags: pandas

I want to select all the numbers with'%' in my pandas.df and turn it into forms of float(e.g. from 2% to 0.02). The target numbers spread occasionally, so can't be accomplished by rows/columns.I tried the following code:

`df.applymap(lambda x: str(x).contains('%').strip("%").astype(float)/100)`

It didn't work...

Comment: What problem did you have ?

Comment: I did't know how to position the numbers with'%'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'percent_column':['2%','3%','6%','0.08'],'Other_percent_column':['0.04','0.03','3%','4%']})
df=df.applymap(lambda x: float(x.rstrip('%'))/100 if '%' in x else float(x))
print(df)
```

**Result:**

```
   percent_column  Other_percent_column
0            0.02                  0.04
1            0.03                  0.03
2            0.06                  0.03
3            0.08                  0.04
```